# How to preserve PHP include() while creating new file with ob_get_contents() and file_put_contents()

Tags: php, include, ob-start

I want to create new file with dynamic contents in it using ob_start() and ob_get_contents() to grab the whole created page. Then I am using file_put_contents() to create the page with that generated content. However, the problem is, it parses the PHP include() and stores only the HTML content. Is there any way that will preserve the PHP include() so that I don't have to change every file code if we want minor updates ?

Comment: carzy roll-your-own caching, or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a page controller of some sort? If yes, put all the common elements in that page controller (or another view that is included in the controller) outside the output buffer. If no, write one (or find a open source one, [like this](http://php-ease.com/classes/page.html)).

For example;

```
// Page controller
include 'path/to/Page.class.php';
$page->contentfile = getpage(); // get the filename of the page using the url string
$page->header = "..."; // header string
$page->footer = "..."; // footer string
ob_start();
include_once($page->contentfile);
$content = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

echo $pageobj->display($content);
```

In page.php you can set your title, etc using something like `$page->title = '';`, and these settings will be remembered in the page controller.

Remember you need to clean the output buffer (`ob_end_clean();`) before the end of the file, or the page content could be outputted twice.

The above code is just an example, but it should point you in the right direction.

Comment: thanks worldofjr, so much for this... however i found quite simple solution using this  

<?php echo '<?php include("../inc/head.php"); ?>'; ?>